# How to nurture an unprepared student

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, undergraduate-research

**What and how much scaffolding is necessary for a motivated undergraduate student who doesn't have the ideal prerequesites for work?** This could be for a number of reasons:

- He didn't realize the purpose of certain classes until later.
- He had troubles grasping concepts on his own and didn't have as much help as he should.
- Really bad classes.

Whatever they are, he's willing to catch up. How to deal with this situation?

Comment: I would spend some time identifying the gaps this student has in their knowledge and then maybe devise a plan on how to catch up with this knowledge.

Comment: A related question some of the answers might be relevant (though I did not find a real answer to your question): http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/1137/61

Comment: The related question seems to be treating with overly basic matters. As an example for my question, consider a student who knows linear algebra but not dual spaces and linear functionals very well.

Comment: Do you think you could phrase your question so that it is not so broad? Right now it says: *For some reason, a motivated undergraduate is behind where he should be in his work. How should an instructor [even this is implicit...] respond?*

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I feel it is in the same spirit as [how to nurture a good student](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/807/how-to-nurture-a-good-student?rq=1). Quoting the first sentence, *When you encounter a very bright student in a first-year (college/university) class (and who is therefore bored), what do you do?*

Comment: I also think this is far too broad. It should at least be asked from the point of view of his instructor in a current class, and perhaps even from the point of view of his instructor in a specific type of class. For example "When a calculus student knows no trigonometry, how best can I help him catch up?" probably even has different answers than "When an abstract algebra student knows nothing about matrices, how best can I help him catch up?" And "My research student doesn't seem to know how proofs work" would be even more different.